# Extracting alphanumeric phrase from a string

Tags: perl

Trying to extract the alphanumeric characters from this string:

```
A_phase_I-II,_open-req_project_id_PX15RAD001
```

The problem is: the term **PX15RAD001** can occur anywhere in the string.

Trying to extract the alpha-numeric part using the below expression. But this returns the entire string. I thought Alum was a valid keyword for alpha-numerics. Is that not the case?

```
(my $string = $line ) =~ s/\P{Alnum}//g;
  print $string;
```

How can I extract the alphanumeric part of the afore mentioned string?

Thanks in advance.
-simak

Comment: how does the output needs to look like?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The output I need to extract is: PX15RAD001.  This term can occur anywhere in the string - can be at the beginning or anywhere else.

Comment: “But it is always preceeded by "_"...” this is not good enough. `_phase`, `_project`, and `_id` are also preceded by underscore. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @simak That entire string (except the comma and dash) is alphanumeric. You need to find a way to tell your various strings apart. We cannot tell you what your input looks like (because we are not mindreaders), you have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end as per your input:

```
> echo "A_phase_I-II,_open-req_project_id_PX15RAD001"|perl -lne 'print $1 if(/id_([A-Z0-9]*)/)'
PX15RAD001
```

In the middle:

```
> echo "A_phase_I-II,_open-req_id_PX15RAD001_project" | perl -lne 'print $1 if(/id_([A-Z0-9]*)/)'
PX15RAD001
```

or in your terms:

```
$line=~m/id_([A-Z0-9]*)/g;
print $1;
```

Comment: Thanks. If I were to assign this to a variable. is this correct? my ($string =  $line) =~ s/(A-Z0-9]*)/

Comment: `$line =~ m/id_(\w*)_?/;my $string = $1;`

Comment: This wont work since it assumes that the term always preceeds id_. that may or may not be the case. The alphanumeric term could occur at the beginning of the string as well.

Comment: it would be easier if you show us from beginning some variations of the problem :/

Comment: for example, is the extracting string always the same length, does it always start with Letters, followed by some numbers and so on. it would make it easier to extract an pattern for that case when we have more informations =)

Comment: Okay-The extracting term is always 12 characters long and is always alpha-numeric. The term can occur anywhere in the string. Can be at the beginning,middle or the end. The length of the string itself varies. If the alpha-numeric term is at the beginning, it is followed by a "_"(underscore). Anywhere else, it is preceeded by an "_"(underscore). Hope this clarifies. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Paulchenkiller That's after taxes.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and Sorry for the confusion.When I say alpha-numeric from that string,i literally mean the alpha and the numeric part of the string which is:PX15RAD001. This is supposed to be 12 characters long -have to see where I dropped the other 2.As I said, the challenge is that, that "term" can occur anywhere in the string and I dont have anything to identify it except that it is a 12 digit combo of numbers and letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some testcases, produced with the comments of @Vijay s Answer:

```
my @line = (
  'A_phase_I-II,_open-req_project_id_PX15RAD001',
  '_PX15RAD001_A_phase_I-II,_open-req_project_id',
  'A_pha3333se_I-II,_ope_PX15RAD001_n-req_project',
  'A_phase_I-II,_PX15RAD001_open-req_projec123123123t_id',
  'A_phase_I-II_PX15RAD001_roject_id'
);
foreach my $string ( @line ) {
  $string =~ m{_([^_]{10})_?}g;
  print $1 . "\n" if $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of questions are hard to answer because there is not enough information. What information we have is:

- You say your target string is "alphanumeric", but the entire input string is alphanumeric, except for some punctuation, so that really doesn't tell us anything.
- You say it is 12 characters long, but the sample you show is 10 characters long.
- You seem to think that "alphanumeric" does not include underscore.

So, the reliable information I can *sense* from you is:

- Target string is always delimited by underscore `_`
- Target string is 10-12 characters, all alphanumeric except underscore.

The "reliable" solution based on this rather skimpy information is:

```
my $str = "A_phase_I-II,_open-req_project_id_PX15RAD001";

for my $field (split /_/, $str) {
    if (length($field) <= 12 and    
        length($field) >= 10 and    # field is 10-12 characters
        $field !~ /\W/) {           # and contains no non-alphanumerics
        # do something
    }
}
```

By splitting on underscore, we can easily isolate each field in the string and perform simpler tests on it, such as the ones above.